# How to cluster label (in a multilabel classification problem) which mostly appear together in a class

Tags: python, classification, multilabel-classification, dataframe

To cluster label (in a multilabel classification problem) which mostly appear together in a dataframe? For example, I have this dataframe:

```
text     |   genre
===========================
text 1   | [action,mistery,horror,thriller]
text 2   | [drama,romance]
text 3   | [comedy,drama,romance]
text 4   | [scifi,mystery,horror,thriller]
text 5   | [horror,mystery,thriller]
```

How can I cluster the tag that often appear together? For example, genre "mystery","horror","thriller" often appear together (3 times), genre "drama","romance" often appears together (2 times).

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty here is the design: if one just represents every "class" as an instance with a vector of its co-occurrences with other "classes", then the clustering will only group the full group of instances/classes by how similar they are with other groups.

Instead I think that an instance should represent a pair of "classes", using the [PMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_mutual_information) as a measure of how strongly they are associated.

An advanced option would be to represent each "class" as a node in a graph and add an edge between any two classes which occur together, weighted by their PMI value. Then use a graph-clustering algorithm to group the "classes".